# code igniter: how to get rid of index.php in url on windows?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My windows hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

My code works fine for:

```
http://example.com/index.php/home/myData/5
```

I am trying to get rid of index.php

I added .htaccess on root :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and changed my application/config/config.php to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

My httpd.conf is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
       <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.com
        ServerName example.com
        <Directory C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\example.com\>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

But when trying to fetch `http://example.com/home/myData/5` 
I got a 404 error and apache log shows:

```
 [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-5.3.8.1/home/myData
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: did you enable .htaccess? apache doesn't look for them by default. and given that rewrite you're trying to do, you'll also need to have path_info enabled.

Comment: yes it enabled :if I put some "hello world", I will het a error500 !

Comment: Which apache version is your server using. Are you sure that you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: yes: mod_rewrite is enabled: I use for other websites (withiut code igniter)

Comment: Just for testing try to change `[L,QSA]` with this [L]

Comment: I found the problem ! 
Infact "home" was reserved by easyphp directory !

Comment: @yarek delete your question then since it's resolved.